# Java: When to use String[] args over String args[]

Tags: java, string, arguments

I already searched, but I couldn't find what I was looking for, so I come with a new question, hoping y'all can tell me, When should I use

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

over

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Comment: They are the same. I prefer the first form as it clearly shows the `[]` are *part of the type*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between the two, other than perhaps readability.

Creating arrays like `String args[]` is allowed simply to add some likeness to C/C++.

You should always prefer `String[] args`.

Note that there is a third option too, using varargs:

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tend to use `String[] args` but i wasnt sure

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are same. Use whatever you feel free. But in Java docs your second style is discouraged. [Take a look](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) I am quoting from Java doc,

> You can also place the brackets after the array's name:
>
> // this form is discouraged float anArrayOfFloats[];

Answer (score 0):

They're the same, but `public static void main(String[] args)` is more commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

Java naming conventions favor `String[] args` over `String args[]`.  You should always use the former in all your code.

The reason for this is practical.

Java is a statically typed language.  Every variable in Java must have a known type.

The class literal for a String arg is `String.class`

The class literal for a String array, eg. String[] args, is `String[].class`

The notation that keeps the brackets with the type name makes it immediately clear to the reader that the type is an array type (which is different from the corresponding non-array type). Although unlikely, it is possible that a naive reader would conclude that the class object for `String args[]` was `String.class` ... which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between ***(String[] args)*** and ***(String args[])***. It's
just a parameter in the function. 
  In fact,you can claim an array with different types.for example,you can claim an array 
of double,you can write **'*double[] array*'** or **'*double array[]* '**