# Difference between string (Java)

Tags: java, string, arguments

What's the difference between

```
String args []
```

and

```
String [] args
```

If anyone could tell me, it would be great!

Comment: Nothing. Not one thing. Nada. Zip. Etc.

Comment: In this situation: nothing. In this situation: `String[] args, args2` something. Hold tight for the duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between int\[\] array and int array\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array) among others. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110635/java-when-to-use-string-args-over-string-args?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean the same thing: create an array of Strings. Its Java convention however for the declaration to be String[] args.